# Проблема в адаптации меню

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

/*Menu*/
.nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;  
}

.menu{
    min-width: 1580px;
    background-color: #4ccfc1;
    padding: 0 120px 0 100px;
}

.menu ul{
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
}

.menu ul li{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
}


.menu ul a:last-child li{
    border:none
}


/*end Menu*/
```

```html
<!--- Menu --->
       <div class="nav">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Sale</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Handbags</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Wallets</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Accessories</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Mens Store</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Shotes</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Vintage</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Contact us</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--- end menu ---->
```

Хочу адаптировать меню таким образом, что бы когда экран уменьшался, пункты меню перескакивали на новую строку. Но не знаю как это сделать. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так это должно выглядеть при адаптации.

Comment: Что используете ? flex-box или что то еще ?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Да верстал на флексах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    ul{
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    li{
      padding: .5rem 1rem;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    li:last-child{
      border: none;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem 1</li>
  <li>lorem 2</li>
  <li>lorem 3</li>
  <li>lorem 4</li>
  <li>lorem 5</li>
  <li>lorem 6</li>
  <li>lorem 7</li>
  <li>lorem 8</li>
  <li>lorem 9</li>
  <li>lorem 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Логика думаю понятна, а стилизацию подтяните.

Comment: Semenov можете подсказать что именно нужно указать в media запрос, просто только учусь адаптации

Comment: Ничего, как я написал уже адаптивно из-за flex-box, проверьте выполнив данный код.

Comment: Semenov Так я попробовал сделать так же как вы, но почему-то не чего не изменилось? С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Этот код работает, покажите свой найдем ошибку.

Comment: Semenov Так я исправил вопрос и добавил код

Comment: Не тому задаете flex

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67398/discussion-between-brafik-and-ruslan-semenov).

Comment: .nav{
      height: 35px;
      position: relative;
  }

  .menu{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      /*min-width: 1580px;*/
      background-color: #4ccfc1;
      padding: 0 120px 0 100px;
  }

Comment: Semenov  ага спасибо всё заработало